# Why do some default bindkey keys do not work in tcsh?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tcsh

I'm using tcsh and I'm seeing that some of my custom and some of the default bindkey bindings do not work. Why don't they work?

For example:

I load some default bindings: `bindkey -e`

I check the default bindings for backward-word `bindkey | grep backward-word` and see:

```
"\302"         ->  backward-word
"\342"         ->  backward-word
"^[B"          -> backward-word
"^[b"          -> backward-word
```

When I try to use backward-word, Alt+Shift+b works just fine, but Alt+b does not work. What gives?

I try to create a new binding for backward-word `bindkey "^[u" backward-word`, but when I try to use it (Alt+u), it acts like backward-char instead.

Comment: that new binding works for me on Ubuntu 12.04 with tcsh 6.17.06 (alt+u -> backword one word). What kind of system are you on? Sometimes it helps to make temporary new account with nothing but standard setup to try things out.

Comment: I'm running on Red Hat 5, using Putty or NoMachine NX from Windows 7. I just tried connecting from a different Windows 7 machine and the bindings from the above example work. Seems like something in Windows is intercepting those keys.

Comment: If you press `Ctrl+V` then `Alt+u`, what is inserted? What does `ESC u` do?

Comment: I see `^[OD`. `ESC u` does backward-word -- seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue. I was running a Linux VM on top of Windows 7. Another program in Windows 7 (AutoHotkey) was overriding those key bindings.